# Get Changeset() function from Run class jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am implementing a plug-in in Jenkins which is compatible with workflow which means that I am implementing *SimpleBuildStep* interface which has a perform method which is different from the regular method which uses AbstractBuild instead of Run

The AbstractBuild class has a function called getChangeSet which is not available in Run class. I need this function to get the changes from SCM. I have tried all types of casting. But it is not working. How can I get this function within Run?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by looping through all the Items in the ItemGroup for the parent of the parent of the Run.  My requirement was to get the most recent change user from the changesets for the Runs.  Here's how I did it and I hope it helps you solve your problem.

```
    private String getChangeUser(Run<?, ?> run) throws AbortException {
    log("Started getChangeUser()");
    String userName = null;
    UserIdCause user = (UserIdCause) run.getCause(Cause.UserIdCause.class);
    if (user != null && user.getUserName() != null) {
        log("Build initiated by: " + user.getUserName());
        if (!user.getUserName().contains("anonymous")) {
            userName = user.getUserName();
        }
    }
    if (userName == null) {
        log("Getting username from changelog for run: " + run.getFullDisplayName());
        log("Getting username from changelog for run.parent:" + run.getParent().getFullDisplayName());
        ItemGroup<?> ig = run.getParent().getParent();
        nextItem: for (Item item : ig.getItems()) {
            if (!item.getFullDisplayName().equals(run.getFullDisplayName())
                    && !item.getFullDisplayName().equals(run.getParent().getFullDisplayName())) {
                continue;
            }
            log("Item: " + item.getFullDisplayName());
            for (Job<?, ?> job : item.getAllJobs()) {
                if (job instanceof AbstractProject<?, ?>) {
                    //log("Job: " + job.getFullName());
                    AbstractProject<?, ?> p = (AbstractProject<?, ?>) job;
                    //log("Project: " + p.getFullName());
                    for (AbstractBuild<?, ?> b : p.getBuilds()) {
                        log("Build: " + b.getFullDisplayName());
                        for (Entry entry : b.getChangeSet()) {
                            if (entry.getAuthor() != null) {
                                log("entry.getAuthor().getId(): " + entry.getAuthor().getId());
                                log("entry.getAuthor().getDescription(): " + entry.getAuthor().getDescription());
                                log("Change user: " + entry.getAuthor().getFullName());
                                userName = entry.getAuthor().getFullName();
                                break nextItem;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return userName;
}
```